# Customizing emacs conf mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am editing some proprietary config files that Emacs autodetects as `Conf[JavaProp]`, i.e. using `conf-javaprop-mode` from `conf-mode.el`.  That mode is almost perfect, except that these files don't have c or c++ style comments, i.e.

```
//foo
```

or

```
/* foo */
```

should **not** be highlighted as comments.  Could anyone provide me with some guidance for how I can make my own extensions to `conf-mode` and automatically load them or whatever from my `.emacs` ?

Comment: Can you manually switch the mode to `conf-windows-mode` or `conf-unix-mode`?  I think the `//` comment styling is specifically a feature of `conf-javaprop-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `conf-mode-initialize` to set the comment syntax.  For example, here is a simple one for `.ctags` where `#` should only start a comment when preceded by spaces.  Just modify which conf mode you want to inherit from, and remove the propertize function/syntax table unless you want those modified as well.

```
(require 'conf-mode)

(defun dotctags-propertize (start end)
  (goto-char start)
  (funcall
   (syntax-propertize-rules
    ("^\\s-*#.*" (0 "<")))
   (point) end))

(defvar dotctags-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((st (make-syntax-table conf-windows-mode-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\; "." st)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">" st)
    st))

;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode dotctags-mode conf-windows-mode "Conf[cTags]"
  "Conf Mode for ctags config."
  :syntax-table dotctags-mode-syntax-table
  (conf-mode-initialize "#")
  (setq-local comment-end "")
  (setq-local syntax-propertize-function #'dotctags-propertize))

;;;###autoload
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ctags\\'" . dotctags-mode))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own derived mode from conf-mode and then make it the default mode for your propietary file

```
(define-derived-mode conf-my-mode conf-unix-mode "Conf[MyMode]"
  "Conf mode of my own"
  (conf-mode-initialize "#" 'conf-my-mode-font-lock-keywords))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.your-extension\\'" . conf-my-mode))
```